# how to connect two computers over the same network using java sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, client

I am not able to connect two different machines over the same network using the following client server programs.
the code however runs fine on the same machine.
I think in the client program it goes in an infinite loop just before `socket.accept()`;
please suggest a possible solution.

server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;

class server{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            int one,zero;
            one=zero=0;
            ServerSocket sock=new ServerSocket(2000);
            Socket soc=sock.accept();
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("Connection Established");
            String msg =dis.readLine();
            System.out.println("MESSAGE : "+msg);
            for(int i=0;i<msg.length();i++){
                if(msg.charAt(i)=='0')
                    zero++;
                else
                    one++;
            }
            System.out.println("Ones are "+one);
            System.out.println("Zeros are "+zero);

            soc.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }
}
```

client.java

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    class client{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            try{
                Socket soc=new Socket("localhost",2000);//or ipv4 address for different computers
                BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                PrintStream pr=new PrintStream(soc.getOutputStream());

                System.out.println("Enter message..");
                String msg =is.readLine();
                pr.println(msg);
                System.out.println("YOU ENTERED.."+msg);
                soc.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println(e);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you change this line: `Socket soc=new Socket("localhost",2000);` with the server ip?

Comment: yes. i did. ipconfig in cmd-> ipv4 address

Comment: Check your firewall settings...

Comment: done. no issues. it just runs into an infinite loop at Socket soc=new Socket("localhost",2000);//or ipv4 address for different computers

Comment: It is supposed to be like that in this line: `Socket soc=sock.accept();`. If the client does not connect, It will wait forever.

Comment: well my client is unable to connect. it still does not work. when i run the client program it doesnt even print "Enter message.." so there is some other error i guess. however on the same computer it works nicely

Comment: Well, first, can you ping the other box OK?

Comment: The client doesn't go 'into an infinite loop'. There is no loop. Don't just guess. The client gets an exception. Post it, and the stack trace, in your question. Either you got the target IP address of the connect wrong, the server wasn't running, or the computers aren't on the same network and either aren't reachable from each other or there is a firewall in the way.

Comment: it does ping fine with no loss. if i move the line System.out.println("Enter message.."); before  Socket soc=new Socket("localhost",2000);//or ipv4 address for different computers it does print the line. however if it is as it is in the above code the program does not execute after line  Socket soc=new Socket("localhost",2000);//or ipv4 address for different computers

Comment: Leave it running for a couple of minutes so it actually gets to the 'connection timeout' that it obviously throws eventually, and then paste the exception you got here into your question. It is looking very like a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is how I figured it out : UDP Broadcast. It will allow the client to connect to server regardless of its IP, so you don't have to hardcode the IP Address, only the port used for UDP (see below).

Here is how it works :

1.Server watch port n

2.Client send message at all port n he can reach

3.When a message reach server's port, Server response with to the sender and include its IP address

4.Client create a socket and connect to the IP address he got from the server

Here is the tutorial that helped me : http://michieldemey.be/blog/network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast/

Comment: How can you possibly know you had the same problem when we don't know what the problem was?